# Object Finding with the help of javaCV

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

The program to find the presence of  an object in an image using the JavaCV ObjectFinder class is working well when the input images are almost the same size.

But that same code, using a smaller image containing an object and the bigger image containing a scene, is not working.

The following exception occured:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.depth() == dst.depth() && src.size == dst.size) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\copy.cpp, line 557
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: It was a built-In code with javaCV , not done by myself.

Comment: Here is the link...........https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/ObjectFinder.java?r=632398ce58f09224001b8a77bde1a72f62ca01b8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the drawback of ObjectFinder class provided by javacv.The input images must be in almost same size and depth in order to compare and find the presence of an object in a scene.I got this after several experiments.